# Chrome --host-rules results in failed SSL handshake

Tags: google-chrome, ip-address

When I open chrome or chromium with the command line flag `--host-rules=MAP * XX.XX.XX.XX`, I get a failed SSL handshake:

> [14865:14877:0908/163850.072936:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200

Here's the background: there are some web servers which ordinarily operate behind a node balancer. In order to run a battery of tests, I want to bypass the node balancer and make requests to each of the servers individually, specifying the servers by IP address. (I need to deploy this setup to various other workstations, and I cannot use a solution that requires root user permissions.)

It seems that although I enter `https://` `mysite.com` into the Chrome address bar, Chrome uses the ip address `XX.XX.XX.XX` during the SSL handshake, and of course, the SSL cert's CN doesn't match that.

Is there a way to:

1. Have Chrome resolve a given hostname to a given IP address
2. While supporting SSL
3. Without needing root (e.g. to edit `/etc/hosts`)
   ?

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem myself, but according to https://datacadamia.com/web/browser/chrome#dns_resolver, the switch was renamed to `--host-resolver-rules`.

Using the current switch name resolved the SSL handshake errors.